# Error in calling POST api in react native by handling action in redux

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, react-redux, multipartform-data

i am fetching some data by using POST api call in which i have data and a token value for header, but i am getting bad response and i checked many docs but can't figure out the error, here is the code:

```
export const shareUserProfileHandler = (sharedReceiverData) => {
    return dispatch => {
        let formData = new FormData();
        for (let key in sharedReceiverData) {
            formData.append(key, sharedReceiverData[key]);
        }
         let requestConfig = {
             method: 'POST',
             headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                 'Authorization': 'Token 97a74c03004e7d6b0658b14ddb'
             },
             body: formData
         };

        fetch(`http://api.com`, requestConfig)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            alert('share user card api worked')

        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert('api error ' + error)
        })
    }
};
```

the above is catching error and showing - SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token'<'

Comment: Probably the response is not JSON but some error page. `<` is probably the start of an HTML document. Check status-code/content in Network tab of DevTools.

Answer (score 1):

Your response doesn't seem to be a JSON.

Replace

```
.then((response) => response.json())
```

For

```
.then((response) => { console.log('response', response); response.json() })
```

And check what is wrong with the response before the error.

Comment: i did same thing in other project it runs successfully but here is shows error....i replaced with your code now it shows the value undefined now

Comment: If the response is undefined, you can't convert it to JSON. Can you tell what is the API?

Comment: i am giving input params like mobile_number as form-data and getting response output in json as {
    "id": 64,
    "rec_name": "",
    "mobile_number": "",
    "mobile_country_code": "",
    
}...

Comment: i have updated my code little bit have a look, but error remains still same

Comment: Can you post what is in the response variable before the .json() method?